# How do I save multiple objects to a JSON column in MySQL and Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4 and I have a problem in that when I save out a group of checkboxes, it only saves one of them if I save it like this:

```
 <label class="checkbox-inline"> {!! Form::checkbox('languages[name]', 'English') !!} English</label><br/>
 <label class="checkbox-inline"> {!! Form::checkbox('languages[name]', 'French') !!} French</label><br/>
 <label class="checkbox-inline"> {!! Form::checkbox('languages[name]', 'Spanish') !!} Spanish</label><br/>
```

But it gives me a workable format in that I can run searches on name. The output here is just the first one I checked but in this format:

```
{"name": "English"}
```

If I take out the array field name in the [].

```
 <label class="checkbox-inline"> {!! Form::checkbox('languages[]', 'English') !!} English</label><br/>
 <label class="checkbox-inline"> {!! Form::checkbox('languages[]', 'French') !!} French</label><br/>
 <label class="checkbox-inline"> {!! Form::checkbox('languages[]', 'Spanish') !!} Spanish</label><br/>
```

It saves all the values but it doesnt give me a workable format for my searches etc. The output here is:

```
["English", "French"]
```

My function in Laravel is like this

```
        public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request;
    dd($data['languages']);
    $resource = Resource::create([
        'user_id' => auth()->id(),
        'status_id' => $status,
        'title' => $data['title'],
        'languages' => $data['languages'],
    ]);
    return redirect($resource->path());
}
```

The column in MySQL called 'languages' is a JSON type.

Now ideally, I would like to get something similar to {"name": "English"} but not just saving as one item but all of them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline"> {!! Form::checkbox('languages[][name]', 'English') !!} English</label><br/>
<label class="checkbox-inline"> {!! Form::checkbox('languages[][name]', 'French') !!} French</label><br/>
<label class="checkbox-inline"> {!! Form::checkbox('languages[][name]', 'Spanish') !!} Spanish</label><br/>
```

It will give you:

```
"languages" => array [
    0 => array: [
        "name" => "English"
    ],
    1 => array: [
        "name" => "French"
    ],
    2 => array: [
        "name" => "Spanish"
    ]
]
```